# Discrepancies in uv coordinates of a ShapeBufferGeometry on three.js

Tags: three.js, uv-mapping

I'm generating uv coordinates in 2d `ShapeBufferGeometry` in the way I've seen in three.js source code, but something must be missing. I can't find a reason but, for some shapes, the points I calculate are "kind of" in the reverse order, in respect to the uvs calculated by three. Other times my points are goods and equals the ones calculated by three.

I've made a simple demo where I create 4 shapes based on svg paths (a simple form of the official svg loader). For every shape I create my own uv points and confront them with the vs points calculated by three. For some reason, the second set of uvs is wrong.

What is missing from my algorithm? Aren't uv points on 2d shapes calculated this way even in three.js source code?

```js
const {Shape, ShapeBufferGeometry} = THREE; 

const points2array = points =>
  points.reduce((tot, point, i) => {
    const idx = i * 2;
    tot[idx] = point.x;
    tot[idx + 1] = point.y;
    return tot;
  }, new Float32Array((points.length - 1) * 2));

const arrayAreEquals = (a1, a2) => {
  return a1.join("-") === a2.join("-");
};
const parseSvgPath = definition => {
  const p = new Shape();
  let lastX = 0;
  let lastY = 0;

  definition.forEach(bs => {
    switch (bs[0]) {
      case "M":
        p.moveTo(bs[1], bs[2]);
        lastX = bs[1];
        lastY = bs[2];
        break;
      case "H":
        p.lineTo(bs[1], lastY);
        lastX = bs[1];
        break;
      case "V":
        p.lineTo(lastX, bs[1]);
        lastY = bs[1];
        break;
      case "L":
        p.lineTo(bs[1], bs[2]);
        lastX = bs[1];
        lastY = bs[2];
        break;
      case "C":
        p.bezierCurveTo(bs[1], bs[2], bs[3], bs[4], bs[5], bs[6]);
        lastX = bs[5];
        lastY = bs[6];
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

  return p;
};

const path1 = [
  ["M", 86.1843823832321, 872.5106859767442],
  [
    "C",
    86.1843823832321,
    837.5758574244353,
    86.1843823832321,
    802.6410288721266,
    86.1843823832321,
    767.7062003198178
  ],
  [
    "C",
    77.62876350586899,
    767.6487330044671,
    70.52307758179892,
    761.3164804522894,
    69.16676572516424,
    752.9424605076606
  ],
  [
    "C",
    69.16676572516424,
    797.7197823857083,
    69.16676572516424,
    842.4971039108538,
    69.16676572516424,
    887.2744257889015
  ],
  [
    "C",
    70.52307758179892,
    878.9004061971749,
    77.62876350586899,
    872.5682394002545,
    86.1843823832321,
    872.5106859767442
  ],
  ["Z"]
];

const path2 = [
  ["M", 172.65222400571358, 137.48388635774268],
  ["H", 189.6698420753906],
  ["V", 224.78143268159283],
  ["H", 172.65222400571358],
  ["V", 137.48388635774268],
  ["Z"]
];

const path3 = [
  ["M", 207.14740017508217, 140.2259332997697],
  [
    "C",
    207.14740017508217,
    162.57569399538315,
    207.14740017508217,
    184.9254546909966,
    207.14740017508217,
    207.27521503370772
  ],
  [
    "C",
    212.81992129835598,
    207.27521503370772,
    218.49246359576745,
    207.27521503370772,
    224.16500624608122,
    207.27521503370772
  ],
  [
    "C",
    224.16500624608122,
    189.8467227044548,
    224.16500624608122,
    172.41821943523075,
    224.16500624608122,
    154.98971616600673
  ],
  [
    "C",
    215.6093870158158,
    154.93218426953638,
    208.50369615111362,
    148.5999962984784,
    207.14740017508217,
    140.2259332997697
  ],
  ["Z"]
];

const path4 = [
  ["M", 241.64254387743972, 259.9104933629545],
  [
    "C",
    241.64254387743972,
    266.86288841179913,
    245.7391956877056,
    273.23298585307725,
    252.1793827006818,
    275.9596857801452
  ],
  [
    "C",
    258.63565958794584,
    278.69319248665875,
    266.044712322569,
    277.1609193114356,
    270.93427418233006,
    272.1613119293537
  ],
  [
    "C",
    275.807530897404,
    267.1784194115222,
    277.2311807465509,
    259.739448326223,
    274.6196949488009,
    253.29540585568543
  ],
  [
    "C",
    272.0027169326503,
    246.83783664022096,
    265.7852479689919,
    242.52102990999816,
    258.7751272803175,
    242.52102990999816
  ],
  [
    "C",
    258.7368084434364,
    242.52102990999816,
    258.6984684324176,
    242.52102990999816,
    258.6601495955365,
    242.52102990999816
  ],
  [
    "C",
    258.6601495955365,
    230.85035448266098,
    258.6601495955365,
    219.17970093526603,
    258.6601495955365,
    207.50904703496877
  ],
  [
    "C",
    249.12653188515915,
    207.57398846800282,
    241.64254352453744,
    215.45796440533448,
    241.64254352453744,
    224.89814382244174
  ],
  [
    "C",
    241.64254387743972,
    236.56892723788087,
    241.64254387743972,
    248.23968877337776,
    241.64254387743972,
    259.9104933629545
  ],
  ["Z"]
];

const shape1 = parseSvgPath(path1);
const geometry1 = new ShapeBufferGeometry(shape1);
const shape2 = parseSvgPath(path2);
const geometry2 = new ShapeBufferGeometry(shape2);
const shape3 = parseSvgPath(path3);
const geometry3 = new ShapeBufferGeometry(shape3);
const shape4 = parseSvgPath(path4);
const geometry4 = new ShapeBufferGeometry(shape4);

console.log(
  arrayAreEquals(
    points2array(shape1.getPoints()),
    geometry1.attributes.uv.array
  )
);
console.log(
  arrayAreEquals(
    points2array(shape2.getPoints()),
    geometry2.attributes.uv.array
  )
);
console.log(
  arrayAreEquals(
    points2array(shape3.getPoints()),
    geometry3.attributes.uv.array
  )
);
console.log(
  arrayAreEquals(
    points2array(shape4.getPoints()),
    geometry4.attributes.uv.array
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looking at your output, only your 2nd path appears different, and the difference is just the clock-wise vs counter-clockwise sequencing of the points.

Comment: That's intuitive and right, `ShapeUtils.isClockWise` confirms that analysis. But where does uvs get "reversed" in three js code, and why?